# Calculating the value of a table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have got a table.
I have assigned a different value to each of the lines

```
<table id="number1">
    <tr>
       <td id="value1">My Table</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("value1").value = "100"
</script>
```

I need to be able to get a value for the table "number 1" by adding the different rows of the table through Javascript.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. What is **get a value for table**? What is **assigned a different value to each of lines**? There are no "lines" in HTML. There are no "values" of table or "values" of row in HTML. Name everything with it's own names because now your problem is no reproducable and most people won't be able to help you.

Comment: your question is not clear to understand plz make sure what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var total=0;
var last =1000000;
for(var i=1;i<parseInt(last);i++){
var id ="value" + i;
var element= document.getElementById(id);
if(element!= null){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=i + "00";
  total=parseInt(total)+parseInt(element.innerHTML);
  }
  else
  i=last;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="sum is =" + total;
```

```html
<table id="number1">
    <tr>
       <td id="value1">My Table value 1 </td>
       <td id="value2">My Table value 2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: But my table doesn't necessarily equal 100. I want a code that can calculate the answer if it is 1 or 1000000

Comment: Sorry I took a while to respond,

Comment: If you see this do I still need to give a value to "Value1"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x=document.getElementById("number1");
var y= x.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML=100;
```

```html
<table id="number1">
    <tr>
       <td id="value1">My Table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
for(i=1;i<100000;i++){
  $("#value"+i).html(i);
}
```